# How to find email address form wordpress custom contact form

Tags: php

Here is `<input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo $contact_form_email; ?>">`

This is code of WordPress custom form.

Need to find-out.

How to change email any idea?

Comment: What do you mean 'How to change email'?

Comment: I want to change the email of contact form so if anyone send email I will get information on my email inbox

Comment: So your question is **"How do I change what `$contact_form_email` is defined as?"** yes? Your post needs some clarification.

Comment: Here is in PHP code <input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo $contact_form_email; ?>"> and when see in HTML code its seems like that <input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" value="email@companys.com">

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using contact form 7 wordpress plugin then email address is
>   store in database..so you can get from plugin's database table

Comment: This is custom base PHP contact form not found any plugin how to find email?

Comment: What are you quoting? When using blockquotes you should also post who/where you're quoting from.

Comment: Here is in PHP code <input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo $contact_form_email; ?>"> and when see in HTML code its seems like that <input type="hidden" id="to" name="to" value="email@companys.com">